# How to escape back slash in GitHub markdown

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll

The markdown processor on GitHub reports that, within a code block, the slash in "\n" as an error. There's a little red square around the \ character. Tried all manner of escapes, including ````\```` and ~~~\~~~, to get it to render. Works locally with Jekyll though.

This produces a red square around the slash character when checked in to GitHub:

```js

```js
try {
    text += entry.message + "\n";
    alert(text);
} catch (error) {
    alert('Error: ' + error);
}
```

```

Comment: I believe this is an issue related to GitHub's syntax highlighter. The Markdown is being processed just fine. If you use your browsers "inspect" tool, I suspect you will be able to confirm this.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a workaround such as an alternate way to escape the slash.

Comment: In my experience, this sort of issue has generally been rectified by properly identifying the language. I see you use `js` in your example. Are you sure `js` is a valid abbreviation?

Comment: According to [github/markup](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup), GitHub uses [github/linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist#syntax-highlighting) for syntax highlighting, which [lists](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/vendor/README.md) [atom/language-javascript](https://github.com/atom/language-javascript) as the JavaScript Grammar. That is different that what Jekyll uses and explains the difference in behavior between github.com and GitHub Pages. It also provides a proper location to report bugs, etc.